# Integrating exponential of Brownian motion wrt to time

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Can you please explain which formula I have to use to integrate the exponential of Brownian motion w.r.t to time:
$$\int_0^t e^{uB_s} ds$$

where $B_t$ is Brownian motion and $u$ is a real positive number.

Using stochastic product rule with $d(te^{uB_t})$ I have:
$$ = te^{uB_t} - \frac{u^2}{2} \int_0^t s e^{uB_s}ds- u\int_0^t se^{uB_s} dB_s$$

Is this correct?

Comment: It is not. Hint: apply the integration-by-parts formula to $se^{uB_s}$. Hint 2: The integral over the exponential has no closed form solution.

Comment: So, I have edited the solution. Is it now correct?

Comment: It looks correct.